# How do I coax IE9 to allow a link endpoint coming from Gmail to use a HTTP Redirect to PDF?

Tags: http, redirect, iis-7, gmail, internet-explorer-9

I have an email with a link to a web page on my server. The pages link issues a Http Refresh header to redirect to a PDF in the cloud. This redirect works with every other browser and/or web mail client configuration.

When debugging, I discovered that if my link points to localhost, IE allows the redirect. But, If I use localhost.site.com IE9 does not allow it. (Again, only in Gmail)

Fiddler between the test does not show any discernible difference. For what it's worth, I'm using MVC3 and IIS 7.0. There are no javascript errors. If I disable javascript and click the link from Gmail's non-js client, the link redirects properly.

I only encounter this problem when redirecting to PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like it could be an issue with the PDF plugin (I am assuming that you are using Adobe) that IE uses to render the PDF in the browser. You can try disabling the plugin and seeing if this problem still occurs.

To disable the plugin, Open Adobe and go to Edit --> Preferences --> Internet and uncheck the option "Display PDF in browser". Try it with the plugin disabled and see if you will be able to download the file.

Comment: Tested by disabling display in browser, and the PDF downloads. Sent a ticket to MS.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue. I just thought I'd add that interestingly adding the redirecting site domain (i.e. the domain in the embedded link) to trusted sites also seemed to work for me. Obviously not much use for tracking link opening.

Clearly this is some weird combination of IE9, Gmail and Adobe as it works fine from Hotmail and from Gmail in Firefox/Chrome. "Display PDF in browser" also worked for me.